# Postgres constraint exclusion for parameterised, prepared query

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

As of Postgres 9.2, constraint exclusion can now be performed on constraints that use parameterised values (see [5.9.6 Caveats](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ddl-partitioning.html)).

However my guess is that this would not apply to a prepared statement with a parameterized constraint, as query planning is done at PREPARE time. Or has something clever been done to make this work?

Can anyone confirm either way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prepared statement does not change planning here, look at example:

```
so=> create table so81(i int);
CREATE TABLE
so=> create table so82(check (i > 2)) inherits (so81);
CREATE TABLE
so=> create table so83(check (i > 0 and i<=2)) inherits (so81);
CREATE TABLE

so=> insert into so82 select 3;
INSERT 0 1
so=> select * from only so81;
 i
---
(0 rows)

so=> select * from so81;
 i
---
 3
(1 row)

so=> SET constraint_exclusion = on;
SET
so=> prepare so83 (int) as select 1 from so81 where i = $1;
ERROR:  prepared statement "so83" already exists
so=> prepare so84 (int) as select 1 from so81 where i = $1;
PREPARE
so=> explain analyze execute so83(3);
                                                 QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=0.00..42.02 rows=14 width=4) (actual time=0.037..0.039 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Append  (cost=0.00..41.88 rows=14 width=0) (actual time=0.037..0.039 rows=1 loops=1)
         ->  Seq Scan on so81  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1)
               Filter: (i = 3)
         ->  Seq Scan on so82  (cost=0.00..41.88 rows=13 width=0) (actual time=0.030..0.031 rows=1 loops=1)
               Filter: (i = 3)
 Execution time: 0.061 ms
(7 rows)

so=> SET constraint_exclusion = off;
SET
so=> explain analyze execute so83(3);
                                                 QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=0.00..84.02 rows=27 width=4) (actual time=0.030..0.033 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Append  (cost=0.00..83.75 rows=27 width=0) (actual time=0.029..0.032 rows=1 loops=1)
         ->  Seq Scan on so81  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)
               Filter: (i = 3)
         ->  Seq Scan on so82  (cost=0.00..41.88 rows=13 width=0) (actual time=0.025..0.026 rows=1 loops=1)
               Filter: (i = 3)
         ->  Seq Scan on so83  (cost=0.00..41.88 rows=13 width=0) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)
               Filter: (i = 3)
 Execution time: 0.126 ms
(9 rows)
```

Comment: Awesome answer ... thanks. Wasn't aware you could use explain that way.